# PHP - A file with a variable is included but shows UNDEFINED VARIABLE error when implemented

Tags: php, undefined, config

I have a config file which is included in every part of the website. It looks more or less like this (I removed alot of unnecesary lines for the example):

```
//Company info
define("COMPANY_NAME", "Test Company");
define("COMPANY_EMAIL", "email@company.com");
define("META_KEYWORDS", "");
define("META_DESCRIPTION", "");

//**********************************************************************
//Remember to change this when working Local or on the Production Server
define("DB_SERVER", "127.0.0.1"); 
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_SELECTED_DB", "adminpanel");
```

One of the lines of this `config.php` file contains this:

```
$_ITEM_TYPES = array(
    1=>"admin",
    2=>"page",
    3=>"repository"
);
```

I'm working in a file where this `config.php` is included, and I can use constants like COMPANY_NAME, COMPANY_EMAIL and so... but when I'm gonna use the $_ITEM_TYPES array, it throws an undefined variable error :/

I've used the function `get_included_files()` and the file is included indeed! I don't know why I cannot use this array.

PHP File **menu.php**

```
include_once("../config.php");

echo COMPANY_NAME;
//Echoes the value correctly

var_dump($_ITEM_TYPES);
//Throws error
```

Any ideas? Thank you all beforehand.

Comment: Show the file where your using the array and including the config file!

Comment: There it is sir, I edited my question

Comment: Look for an `exit`, `die`, `return`, `unset` etc before the array definition.

Comment: for me it works fine with these lines of code! I would suggest you do fist what AbraCadaver said and otherwise you post the code between the definitions and the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to shoot in the dark here. I am 99% sure that the cause of your problem is that you are including this file somewhere else. By using `include_once` it will not include the file again because it has been included previously, however in another scope which is causing the undefined variable error.

If you want that configuration array to be available globally you can use `$GLOBALS`, but it's bad practice.

Comment: Seems that it was impossible to solve this in the way I wanted. So I had to move the array from there and put it in the class / file I was going to use it. For flexibility I used a json config file for this part.

Comment: Yes. Seems like for some reason it leaves that array out of the scope and cannot be used anywhere. Thing that is hard to do with the system I'm developing because it's a tree of classes, and this config file is included in the top of it. The good thing is that I can use these constants anywhere :P

Comment: @JuanBonnett Well of course. I don't know what kind of system that is that has no configuration class. What you have to do is create a class Config that is going to hold that variable and probably many more inside of it as static members so you can access them everywhere.

Comment: It makes alot of sense

Comment: @JuanBonnett well I didn't invent it, it's how people have been doing it for a long time.